# Under what circumstances can SVG path's commands be omitted?

Tags: svg, graphics

I am working with the SVG code of a map file sourced from Wikipedia, and stumbled upon this weird looking `path` element.

```
<path d="m 36.943395,239.60555 c -2.53599,-0.0564 1.53374,-0.10078 -2.36262,-0.80482 0.32392,1.46137 0.35668,3.39659 -0.2642,6.15571 -0.16424,0.73016 -0.53689,1.39667 -1.02526,1.94642 8.3e-4,0.003 -0.73141,3.09631 3.2815,0.64493 0.79653,-0.4865 0.81727,-3.85406 0.0695,-4.31941 -1.13081,-0.70362 0.19452,-0.0269 0.27789,-1.56755 0.0174,-0.32184 1.91842,-2.01319 0.0232,-2.05529 l 0,1e-5 z"/>
```

It seems to have omitted most of its commands and only has coordinates left, but somehow still renders correctly in Chrome and Firefox. So I suspect there is some standard here (or at least de facto standard). However after some searching, I just cannot find any reference on optional commands and/or command omission.

So can someone please explain how this `path` is interpreted, and if there is any standard on command omission? Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [SVG specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/paths.html#PathDataBNF) explains it.

Generally the prior command repeats except that moves become lines. This is explained in text [here](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/paths.html#PathDataGeneralInformation)

> The command letter can be eliminated on subsequent commands if the same command is used multiple times in a row (e.g., you can drop the second "L" in "M 100 200 L 200 100 L -100 -200" and use "M 100 200 L 200 100 -100 -200" instead).

So your path is equivalent to an m followed by multiple c commands.

Comment: Can you add a bit of explaning? I read the formal specification you linked to carefully, but still couldn't find where it says chained `draw-to`s could have their commands omitted.

Comment: Ah thanks, I see it now. The link in your answer went to `#PathDataBNF`, which is underneath the section you quoted.

Comment: That's the formal grammar which is the definitive answer. Everything else is icing.

Comment: Ah I get it now. It didn't register with me that each `arg` is a full list of coordinates required for that command, and `arg-seq` is one or more `arg`s. I was expecting `drawto-command`s (like `curveto`, for example) to be declared like `( "C" | "c" )?`.